# Panoramic medium format film camera with rise/fall function

Tags: film, panorama, fujifilm

I'm interested about panoramic film cameras. However I'd like to know if any of them offer a shift function, as I could not find any.

I also wonder what is the purpose of the metal grid structure outside of the lens, for example, in the Fuji GX617.

Comment: What's your definition of a panoramic camera? The Noblex 135 S has 4mm of vertical shift, but maybe you don't want to use a rotating-lens camera. You can always just use a wide-angle PC lens on any format, and crop the result to a panoramic format.

Comment: Not an answer, but a guess... I always thought the "cage" / "roll-bar" around Fuji's 617 lenses was to protect the (certainly expensive and maybe fragile) lens from bumps and knocks.

Comment: I meant rise and fall, those are the two features I use the most. I am mostly interested about 120 film.

Comment: This should be split into two questions. One about the availability of shift in a panoramic camera. Another about the cage on the GX617.

Comment: @Bob Cropping a lens with larger coverage than the final image has the same effect as rise/fall if the crop is not centered vertically. That's essentially what view camera movements as well as PC or T/S lenses do with shift movements: The lens projects a larger image circle than recorded by the camera, and the film/sensor is lined up behind the desired portion of that large image circle. Shifting up (rise) causes the camera to record the lower part of the lens' image circle. Shifting down (fall) causes the camera to record the upper part of the lens' image circle.

Comment: Bob: you've got a great answer to your second question, but none to the first. Could you please split this into two, so that can be answered and accepted?

Comment: @mattdm I don't think it would matter. The first question is almost impossible to answer if the correct answer is "no", because no one knows of *every single panoramic camera ever made* in order to be able to confirm that none of them offered vertical shift movements. Especially when one application for such a camera would be aerial reconnaissance, which can often be shrouded in military secrecy.

Comment: @MichaelC Then at least then we get one well-answered question and one unanswerable one, instead of this one which is half-answered and half-unanswerable (which in my mind rounds down to "problematic")

Answer (score 2):

> I wonder what is the purpose of the metal grid structure outside of the lens, for example, in the Fuji GX617.

When you put a set of human hands in the same frame with a GX617, it becomes more apparent just how large the GX617 is.

[image]

The cages on the lenses are there for protection of those somewhat skinny lenses that extend fairly far out of the large camera body. Each lens has its own cage, and the ends of the cage tubes are guide points where the lens is attached to the camera.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there are no 617 format tilt shift cameras available and a search of the more common photography outlets didn't yield anything.

A possible workaround, if you don't need anything super wide, is to use a 4x5 rail camera. There are a handful of 6x12 120 backs available out there. Alternately, just shooting on 4x5 (with shift if needed) and cropping to the desired aspect ratio may be an option that would give you what your looking for with some added flexibility.

I know two landscape photographers who use the latter method to great effect, one shooting on 4x5 and the other on 8x10.